# CSS sprite image not found

Tags: html, css

HTML, The image is just blank like the image is not found. It still resizes though.  Why is this? I have tried with imgur and local image in image folder at [website](https://hostup.org/) problemo is still not solved.

```css
.sprite {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/q0b68yh.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

.sprite-fast_img {
  width: 85px;
  height: 88px;
  background-position: -5px -5px;
}

.sprite-github {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-position: -100px -5px;
}

.sprite-gmail {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-position: -100px -45px;
}

.sprite-linkedin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-position: -100px -85px;
}

.sprite-secure_img {
  width: 85px;
  height: 88px;
  background-position: -140px -5px;
}

.sprite-stackoverflow {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-position: -5px -103px;
}

.sprite-tumblr {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-position: -45px -103px;
}

.sprite-twitter {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-position: -140px -103px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite-secure_img"></div>
```

Thank you for the help & best wishes.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 1):

I think your `div` is missing the `sprite` class:

```css
.sprite {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/q0b68yh.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}

.sprite-fast_img {
    width: 85px;
    height: 88px;
    background-position: -5px -5px;
}

.sprite-github {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: -100px -5px;
}

.sprite-gmail {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: -100px -45px;
}

.sprite-linkedin {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: -100px -85px;
}

.sprite-secure_img {
    width: 85px;
    height: 88px;
    background-position: -140px -5px;
}

.sprite-stackoverflow {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: -5px -103px;
}

.sprite-tumblr {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: -45px -103px;
}

.sprite-twitter {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-position: -140px -103px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite sprite-secure_img"></div>
```

Comment: This is not a good way to do this because you create separate classes with no connection, it is a better way using subclasses inside sprite class for each icon

Comment: Why Would you have a DIV in a .css file? Also I tried that and it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

When you make a `sprite`, the main class is where you put the sprite image and bg definitions. After that you need to create subclass to show the part of sprite you need.

In your code you not defined the subclasses for each icon you need, you just created a new class for each icon but that classes not have conection whit the main class. You need to create the main class `sprite` and subclasses as `sprite.your-icon` and when you call the sprite you will call `<div class="sprite your-icon"></div>`

```css
    .sprite {
        background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/q0b68yh.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .sprite.fast_img {
        width: 85px;
        height: 88px;
        background-position: -5px -5px;
    }
    
    .sprite.github {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-position: -100px -5px;
    }
    
    .sprite.gmail {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-position: -100px -45px;
    }
    
    .sprite.linkedin {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-position: -100px -85px;
    }
    
    .sprite.secure_img {
        width: 85px;
        height: 88px;
        background-position: -140px -5px;
    }
    
    .sprite.stackoverflow {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-position: -5px -103px;
    }
    
    .sprite.tumblr {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-position: -45px -103px;
    }
    
    .sprite.twitter {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-position: -140px -103px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="sprite secure_img"></div>
```